# Can Regex remove multiple surrounding {"TextWithHtml": and } in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, json, string, linq

Is there a way I could manipulate a string containing:

```
{"Correct":true,"Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1 -1 4 -16"}},{"Correct":true,"Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1 -1 4 2147483644"}}]
```

and remove the  `{"TextWithHtml":`  and `}` but leave the inside contents?

Comment: I hope this So could help ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Comment: What you're asking is for a regular expression that will match any valid JSON string value. Why reinvent the wheel? Use a JSON parser to parse the it into a form you can manipulate, and then use a JSON serializer to write it back in the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string sSource = @"{"Correct":true,"Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1
    -1 4 -16"}},{"Correct":true,"Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1
    -1 4 2147483644"}}]"; 

string pattern = @"({"TextWithHtml":)|(?(?<=({"TextWithHtml":)[^}]*)})"; 

string sResult= Regex.Replace(@sSource, @pattern, "");
```

some explanation:

remove

```
{"TextWithHtml":
```

or remove

```
}
```

if it is preceeded by:

{"TextWithHtml": plus some characters that aren't '{'

EDIT:

for {} brackets inside a TextWithHtml string:

({"TextWithHtml":)|(?(?<=(({"TextWithHtml":)(("[^"]*")|null)))})

There is still an issue with escaped quote characters (\") though.

Comment: What's that going to do with something like `{"TextWithHtml":"This is a string with {{{ }}} } stuff in it"}`?

Comment: "This is a string with {{{ }} } stuff in it"} - I don't know if that's wat you want, it may need some improvements, on your original string result is like this: {"Correct":true,"Explanation":null,"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":"1 -1 4 -16"},{"Correct":true,"Explanation" null,"ImageFile":null,"Response":false,"Text":"1  -1 4 2147483644"}]

Comment: My question is what happens if there is a `}` character inside the text that you're trying to keep? It looks to me like your expression will stop matching at that `}`, and not get the entire string.

Comment: @Gemma: This solution will fail if the text contains a `}` character. For example, given the string `"{\"TextWithHtml\":\"This } is bad\"}"`, the result is `"This  is bad"}`. Note that the embedded `}` is removed and the trailing `}` is kept.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should create a class

```
public class YourClassName
{
    public string TextWithHtml{ get; set; }
}
```

And modify your answer class

```
public class Answer : AuditableTable
{
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
    public YourClassName Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public YourClassName Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I could just find a way to change the characters in the source string it would work but I am not sure how to do a regular expression for making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

To match all the data you want, use the following regex:

```
{"TextWithHtml":.*?}
```

Use [Regex.Replace(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) to replace the matches with the substring.

```
string data = match.Value.Substring(16, match.Value.Length-16-1);
```

Next, trim the data if it contains the " marks:

```
data.Trim('"');
```

Comment: That's going to fail if the text to be matched contains a `}` character.